# Dajngo Model embed multiple Abstract Models

Tags: python, django

Suppose I have an `Order` model for storing customers' orders on my site. There will be two address fields: `shipping_address` and `billing_address`. I could write it something like this:

```python
class Order(models.Model):
  order_number = models.CharField()
  time_created = models.DateTimeField()
  ...
  shipping_name = models.CharField()
  shipping_city = models.CharField()
  shipping_street = models.CharField()
  shipping_building = models.CharField()
  billing_name = models.CharField()
  billing_city = models.CharField()
  billing_street = models.CharField()
  billing_building = models.CharField()
  ...
```

Then access fields by `order.shipping_name` and `order.billing_name`, but that is getting really cumbersome when every address needs to contain 15-20 fields.

I tried One-to-One relationships, but code in other places of the application becomes very complicated.

If there would be only one address field I could use an Abstract Model to make it a bit cleaner:

```python
class Address(models.Model):
  class Meta:
    abstract = True
  name = models.CharField()
  city = models.CharField()
  street = models.CharField()
  building = models.CharField()
  ...

class Order(Address, models.Model):
  order_number = models.CharField()
  time_created = models.DateTimeField()
```

But this way I can only have one set of address data and field names from the `Address` class would clash with fields from `Order`.

Is there a way to *inject* or *embed* fields with given prefix in DB to given Model?
I am looking for something similar to `@Embedded` decorator used in Spring Framework models.

I would imagine it looking like so:

```python
class Address(models.Model):
  class Meta:
    abstract = True
  name = models.CharField()
  city = models.CharField()
  street = models.CharField()
  building = models.CharField()
  ...

class Order(models.Model):
  order_number = models.CharField()
  time_created = models.DateTimeField()
  shipping_address = Embedded(Address, prefix='shipping')
  billing_address = Embedded(Address, prefix='billing')
```

And then accessing fields by `order.shipping_address.city` or to not break code in other places maybe `order.shipping_address_city` would also work.

EDIT:
Could similar functionality be achieved using JSONField or HStoreField?

Comment: Why not make a separate model with a `ForeignKey` from `Order` to `Address`, then you can let each `Order` refer to an address. This also avoids data duplication.

Comment: I've done exactly that, but it created problems in Django Admin forms. I tried using reverse inlines, but my application requires also different validation processes for different address types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, the approach of using model factory from https://stackoverflow.com/a/55051990/345811 seems to work the best for me.

Here's sample `models.py` implementation:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

from app.countries import COUNTRIES  # A list of country code/name tuples

ADDRESS_FIELDS = (
    ('first_name', dict(verbose_name=_('First name'), max_length=256)),
    ('last_name', dict(verbose_name=_('Last name'), max_length=256)),
    ('company', dict(verbose_name=_('Company'), max_length=256, required=False)),
    ('street', dict(verbose_name=_('Street address'), max_length=256)),
    ('street2', dict(verbose_name=_('Street address line 2'), max_length=256, required=False)),
    ('street3', dict(verbose_name=_('Street address line 3'), max_length=256, required=False)),
    ('postal_code', dict(verbose_name=_('Postal code'), max_length=16)),
    ('city', dict(verbose_name=_('City'), max_length=64)),
    ('province', dict(verbose_name=_('Province'), max_length=64, required=False)),
    ('country', dict(verbose_name=_('Country'), choices=COUNTRIES, max_length=2)),
)


def address_model_factory(field_prefix, force_optional=False):
    """
    Usage:
    class SomeModel(address_model_factory(''), address_model_factory('billing', True))
    """
    class AbstractAddressModel(models.Model):
        class Meta:
            abstract = True

    for field_name, field_def in ADDRESS_FIELDS:
        required = field_def.get('required', True)
        field_kwargs = {k: v for k, v in field_def.items() if k != 'required'}
        if force_optional or not required:
            field_kwargs.update(blank=True, default="")
        AbstractAddressModel.add_to_class(field_name if not field_prefix else f'{field_prefix}_{field_name}',
                                          models.CharField(**field_kwargs)
                                          )

    return AbstractAddressModel


class Shipment(address_model_factory(''), address_model_factory('billing', True)):
    status = models.Charfield(_('Shipment status'), max_length=20)
```

Which would produce a migration like this:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Shipment',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('first_name', models.CharField(max_length=256, verbose_name='First name')),
                ('last_name', models.CharField(max_length=256, verbose_name='Last name')),
                ('company', models.CharField(blank=True, default='', max_length=256, verbose_name='Company')),
                ('street', models.CharField(max_length=256, verbose_name='Street address')),
                ('street2', models.CharField(blank=True, default='', max_length=256, verbose_name='Street address line 2')),
                ('street3', models.CharField(blank=True, default='', max_length=256, verbose_name='Street address line 3')),
                ('postal_code', models.CharField(max_length=16, verbose_name='Postal code')),
                ('city', models.CharField(max_length=64, verbose_name='City')),
                ('province', models.CharField(blank=True, default='', max_length=64, verbose_name='Province')),
                ('country', models.CharField(choices=[('DE', 'Germany'), ('GB', 'United Kingdom')], max_length=2, verbose_name='Country')),
                ('billing_first_name', models.CharField(blank=True, default='', max_length=256, verbose_name='First name')),
                ('billing_last_name', models.CharField(blank=True, default='', max_length=256, verbose_name='Last name')),
                ('billing_company', models.CharField(blank=True, default='', max_length=256, verbose_name='Company')),
                ('billing_street', models.CharField(blank=True, default='', max_length=256, verbose_name='Street address')),
                ('billing_street2', models.CharField(blank=True, default='', max_length=256, verbose_name='Street address line 2')),
                ('billing_street3', models.CharField(blank=True, default='', max_length=256, verbose_name='Street address line 3')),
                ('billing_postal_code', models.CharField(blank=True, default='', max_length=16, verbose_name='Postal code')),
                ('billing_city', models.CharField(blank=True, default='', max_length=64, verbose_name='City')),
                ('billing_province', models.CharField(blank=True, default='', max_length=64, verbose_name='Province')),
                ('billing_country', models.CharField(blank=True, choices=choices=[('DE', 'Germany'), ('GB', 'United Kingdom')], default='', max_length=2, verbose_name='Country')),
                ('status', models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='Shipment status')),
            ],
            options={},
        ),
    ]
```

Answer (score -1):

Embedding a piece of another model as a reference might be not possible, also, it definitely will be non-standard way. The only recommended solution is to use 2 different models: `Order` and `Address`. Then assign the address in your order as a `ForeignKey`:

```py
class Order(models.Model):
    ...
    shipping_address = models.ForeignKey(
        Address, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="shipped_orders",
        blank=True, null=True
    )
    invoice_address = models.ForeignKey(
        Address, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="invoiced_orders",
        blank=True, null=True
    )
```

It will show as a select box in the admin where you can select shipping and invoice addresses. To make it easier, just use [autocomplete_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields) in your admin.

And if you need to make some verification in the admin page while adding an order, you can set a model that will be used in the admin page, [this part of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form) describes how to do that. In your custom Order form you can verify fields like `def clean_shipping_address(self)`, it is more described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute).

Comment: I wanted to have all of the address fields editable so I used the ForeignKeys and [django-revese-admin](https://github.com/daniyalzade/django_reverse_admin), but it broke saving with other Inline admins that I had in the OrderAdmin

Comment: There will be an Edit button in the select box that will open a small window for editing the selected address information. That will also help you to store the correct address for users and other orders that use this same address. Or, if you don't want to change the address, you can make a copy of the Address provided by the user and assign that newly created address to the order instead of the one provided by the user or from an import. That way you will be able to keep the main address same and modify the copy assigned to the order. You can also male a link between addresses.